# Unable to locate element a div element in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate scenario where in an user searches an item & once the search results come up he clicks on the serving size & the quantity of that particular item.

[image]

But, I'm constantly getting element not found exception when I'm trying to manipulate the text field by changing the value & by selecting the quantity size, even after trying to play with all the locators for that div tag under which these elements(textbox, drop down a few buttons) occur. I verified that these elements don't come under an frame. I also tried injecting javascript to perform the operations, but to no avail.
Could someone please point out where i'm going wrong.

```
<div id="loaded_item">
<input id="food_entry_food_id" type="hidden" name="food_entry[food_id]" value="348096022">
<input id="food_entry_date" type="hidden" value="2017-01-10" name="food_entry[date]">
<p class="food-description">Bananas, raw</p>
<div class="verified-food-container" style="display: block;">
<div class="user_submitted"></div>
<p></p>
<h3 class="secondary-title">How much?</h3>
<input id="food_entry_quantity" class="text short" type="text" size="30" name="food_entry[quantity]" autocomplete="off" value="1.0">
servings of
<select id="food_entry_weight_id" class="select" name="food_entry[weight_id]">
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h3 class="secondary-title">To which meal?</h3>
<select id="food_entry_meal_id" class="select" name="food_entry[meal_id]">
<p></p>
<input id="update_servings" class="button log" type="submit" value="Add Food To Diary" data-food-id="348096022" data-external-id="63109870792493" data-version-id="197946116099837">
<div class="nutritional_info">
</div>
```

Following is my code to find these elements.

```
           @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='searchFoodByName']/form/p/input[4]")
            WebElement searchFoodDatabaseButton;

            @FindBy(linkText = "Bananas, raw")
            WebElement matchedFoodThirdOption;

              @FindBy(xpath="//div[@id='loaded_item']/input[@id='update_servings']")
            WebElement addFoodToDiary;

            @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='date_controls']/form/span/a[2]")
            WebElement clickOnNextDate;

            @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='food_entry_quantity']")
            WebElement foodEntryQuantity;

            @FindBy(css = "select[id='food_entry_weight_id']")
            WebElement foodEntryWeight;

            @FindBy(css = "select[id='food_entry_meal_id']")
            WebElement addFoodToMeal;


            public void searchFoodItem() throws Exception{

                            TextBoxHelper.set(driver,searchFoodDatabase,"Banana");
                            ButtonHelpers.click(driver, searchFoodDatabaseButton);

                            ButtonHelpers.click(driver, matchedFoodThirdOption);

                            Utils.waitForElement(driver, By.xpath(".//*[@id='loaded_item']"), 2000);

                            foodEntryQuantity.clear();
                            foodEntryQuantity.sendKeys("2.0");

                            Select WeightPickerDropDown = new Select(foodEntryWeight);
                            WeightPickerDropDown.selectByIndex(2);

                            Select MealPickerDropDown = new Select(addFoodToMeal);
                            MealPickerDropDown.selectByIndex(2);

                            ButtonHelpers.jsClick(driver, addFoodToDiary);
                            System.out.println("after clicking the add button");

            }
```

Comment: The html is invalid. (How `p` tag can be in `select`?)

Comment: @MoshFeu That HTML markup is from the Website that i'm trying to automate.

Comment: I understand.. but maybe that's the problem. I'm not familiar with this but it makes sense to me that the script will be break because of this but again, not familiar..

Comment: @AdiBoy, could you remove all unnecessary lines of code to leave just those lines that actually could cause your issue (same for `HTML`)?

Comment: @Andersson I could remove the unnecessary lines, but I just wanted to show the other approaches that I have taken to overcome this issue. I'll edit my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavascriptExecutor code might be wrong

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '2.0')", WebElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Blog, i'll take a look at it. However, the javscript code is one of the solution that I thought would work. I have used custom clicks & other solutions, but no luck.

Comment: I tried using what you shared, but i'm still unable to locate the element.

Comment: What message you getting when you try waitForElementToBeVisible.Check first whether element is visible or not?

Comment: I'm getting isEnabled() as true & isDisplayed() as false. The exception i'm getting is : invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable & may not be manipulated.

Comment: sorry for late reply. Can you please share the url on which i can develop and run script?